# How to get the id/key of added firebase item directly in Ionic 2?

Tags: firebase, ionic2, addition

I'm trying to get the id/key of added item after adding processing

for example, this is my add function

```
add(){
    let todayTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm')
    this.afd.list('/questions/').push({
        uemail: this.userService.email,
        title: this.variables.title,
        text: this.variables.text,
        type: this.variables.type
    })
}
```

So how can I get the id directly (when item added successfully) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

`let key = this.afd.list('/questions/').push().key;`

You get the key before pushing your data. It is useful when you need simultaneously add data in different locations using `.update()`